# Run a program in XP compatibility on Win 7 *without* admin rights

Tags: .net-framework, vb.net, windows-7, compatibility, uac

I have a VB.NET program I wrote which uses Process.Start() to launch an '.ARTask' file associated with BMC Remedy User. For reasons beyond the scope of this question (someone else had the same problem [here](https://communities.bmc.com/communities/thread/55019)) I need to run Remedy User under Windows 7's XP compatibility.

My problem is that setting it to run under compatibility mode seems to force it to run as Admin (ie. with UAC) and this seems to break the Process.Start() functionality. Is there a way to get more control over the compatibility mode in Windows 7, so I can run Remedy User under XP compatibility mode without admin rights? Remedy User runs almost fine without XP compatibility settings or Admin rights (short of the problem above) so I'm fairly confident it shouldn't need them.

Just to be clear, I'm *not* talking about the Virtual PC enabled 'XP mode', I'm talking about the right-click -> properties -> compatibility settings.

Comment: If anyone's interested, [this](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7352) did the trick.